# How would I order my youtube video search by highest views?

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm working on a youtube video search for a Chat bot on a website.

I want the search to be ordered by the highest views for a video, as I think that'd be the most accurate result if a user searches for something. That's my code for doing the search:

```
  var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = result;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 25;
```

The youtube API says there is a way to sort by highest views. The [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) says that under optional paramaters there is "order" and you can order by viewCount. I'm struggling to put this into my code for some reason and have been trying for hours.

Comment: If the answer below solved your problem, please accept it or provide some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The page you linked to explains it as this (if this is what you were asking):

```
var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = result;
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 25;
        searchlistRequest.Order = "viewCount";
```

Now when you retrieve your response, they should be ordered by view count (highest to lowest).

```
var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```